# convert each sheet name as data validation separately

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am striving hard and Googled stuff but nothing similar is found.

I have 25+ sheets but i attached an example of 3 sheets where each sheet name is being used as `Data validation` in `Col"B"`.

I want that each sheet name should be converted to Col"B" Data Validation as i attached an example.

and whenever that sheet name goes change B2:B range will automatically change name in the range.

Here are the pictures where you can see that iwant to convert sheet name to data validation just for Col"B".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking please provide a complete example.  What happens to the Sheet named `KIYOG` as a result of the conversion process.

Comment: I have attached an Sheet and also updated the question @Cooper

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow links to offsite resources.  Please post it in your question if you wish my help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want column B on every sheet to be a list of all sheet names the use

```
const unwanted = ['KIYOG' , 'MELAMO' , 'TEGRI'];
const list = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(s => !~unwanted.indexOf(s.getName()));
```

for the validation in column B

```
sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);//Column B
```

Comment: No it should not list of all sheet name. Each sheet name is separate i do not want to use all sheets name to make list of them. In above example there are three sheets and thier validation present Sheet name no all sheets list. Code will load the `KIYOG` sheet name and make data validation then go to `2nd` then `3rd` then so on

Comment: How to determine which sheets to use?

Comment: By putting sheets name.

Comment: Again how do I determine which sheet name is to be put and what does it mean to put the sheets name?

Comment: Sheets name will be `KIYOG` , `MELAMO` , `TEGRI` like this `sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet3",  "Sheet7"]` I do not want to create a loop that will convert every sheet to `Data Validation` because there are some sheets which do not need to convert into data validation.

Comment: That edited question is great. Thanks But how to refer the `Col"B"`

Comment: So it wil be use like this `function myFunction() {

const unwanted = ['KIYOG'];
const list = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(s => !~unwanted.indexOf(s.getName())); 

  sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);//Column B
}
`

Comment: Rote copying isn't acceptable for programmers.   You must learn to use the documentation and think for yourself.  First of all sheet is undefined in your function  and there is no use of `newDataValidation`

Comment: I strongly agree but how to find exact documentation here i searched `how to define undefined sheets in gas` but nothing relevant found

Comment: There's a prerequisite for learning google apps script.  And that is knowing Javascript.

Comment: In your case sheet is a variable and it's and undefined variable